# SQLite Function Error: Entry Point Not Found

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-studio-2005

I am using SQLite as database in my project. I built and executed the project properly in the old version. But after some modifications in other parts of the project a problem occured.

It still could be built, but it is not working.

When I debugged the project, I saw that, `sqlite3_prepare_v2` function of SQLite, caused a problem as:

> Entry Point Not Found.

I replaced this function by the old version `sqlite3_prepare` and it caused a runtime error.

I could not even figure out the problem. It has been working on the same system and the older project.

I researched for solution on the Internet. It is said that, changing error log by regedit solves, but it did not work out.

I would be very glad, if there is someone who has seen and solved out this problem before.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure, that your db connection not closed in time you call sqlite_prepare_v2?

Comment: Yes, sure. I debugged and saw that the connection is opened.

Comment: can you try to create a minimal non working example and post the code?